# Import project, define workspace and open Eclipse from command line?

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a generated Eclipse CDT project from CMake on Linux. I am building a script so that when CMake is done generating the project, it automatically opens Eclipse with a new workspace in a relative path from my project and import the generated project.

So far, I've managed to import the project by doing the following command: `$ eclipse ./`. This properly opens eclipse and brings me to the import window with my project. I can also do the following command to choose a workspace: `$ eclipse -data workspace`. This properly opens a new eclipse project with the workspace folder I passed it. However, if I do `$ eclipse ./ -data workspace`, it simply opens a new project in the workspace folder I specified. It forgets to import my project. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried changing the args order? `eclipse -data workspace ./`

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Yes I did try and I get the same results.